# Product Rule for Arcs in Lie Group

Tags: representation-theory, manifolds, differential-topology, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Fulton and Harris 8.30 begins:

> If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are arcs in $G$ and $\gamma(t) = \alpha(t) \cdot \beta(t)$, then
>
> $$ \gamma(t)' = dm_{\alpha(t)}(\beta'(t)) + dn_{\beta(t)}(\alpha'(t))$$
> where for any $g \in G$, $m_g: G \to G$ is left multiplication by $g$, and $n_g$ is right multiplication by $g$.

I have been very stuck on proving this product rule, and have not been able to find a good stack exchange post for it.

I have tried using the chain rule on manifolds to attack this problem, but it got a little confusing toward the middle for me. I also tried just directly evaluating both sides on an arbitrary smooth map $f: G \to \mathbb{R}$ to see if the differentials are the same as maps.

Evaluating at $t_0$, I got on the left side:

$$ \gamma'(t_0)(f) = D_t(f(\alpha(t) \cdot \beta(t))(t_0)$$

but on the right I got:

$$ \left( d(m_{\alpha(t_0)})_{\beta(t_0)}(\beta'(t_0)) + d(n_{\beta(t)})_{\alpha(t_0)}(\alpha'(t))\right)(f) = D_t(f(\alpha(t_0) \cdot \beta(t)))(t_0) + D_t(f(\alpha(t) \cdot \beta(t_0)))(t_0)$$

It is not immediately obvious to me at all that these two sides should be equal.

- Am I misunderstanding the product rule I am supposed to prove?
- Am I misunderstanding how to apply to right hand side to a smooth function?
- If I am correct, why are the two sides equal?
- Is there a better proof than simply trying to evaluate both sides on a function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equality of the two sides $$D_t(f(\alpha(t) \cdot \beta(t))(t_0)$$ and $$D_t(f(\alpha(t_0) \cdot \beta(t)))(t_0) + D_t(f(\alpha(t) \cdot \beta(t_0)))(t_0)$$ is immediate by the chain rule.  Indeed, writing $g(s,t)=f(\alpha(s)\cdot\beta(t))$, the multivariable chain rule tells us $$D_t(g(t,t))(t_0)=D_t(g(t_0,t))(t_0)+D_t(g(t,t_0))(t_0)$$ and that is exactly the equation you want.

Alternatively, you can prove the original statement directly using the chain rule.  Let $\mu:G\times G\to G$ be the multiplication map, so $\gamma(t)=\mu(\alpha(t),\beta(t))$.  By the chain rule, $$\gamma'(t)=\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}(\alpha(t),\beta(t))\alpha'(t)+\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial y}(\alpha(t),\beta(t))\beta'(t)$$ where the partial derivatives are the derivatives of $\mu$ with respect to its first and second inputs, respectively.  Now $\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}(x,y)$ is just $dn_y(x)$: we are differentiating the function $\mu(x,y)=n_y(x)$ with respect to $x$.  Similarly, $\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial y}(x,y)$ is $dm_x(y)$.  So, plugging these into the equation above, we obtain
$$\gamma'(t)=dn_{\beta(t)}(\alpha(t))\alpha'(t)+dm_{\alpha(t)}(\beta(t))\beta'(t).$$  This differs from the formula you want only in that I am explicitly writing which points we are taking the differentials $dn_{\beta(t)}$ and $dm_{\alpha(t)}$, namely at $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. In the latter half of your answer, I am perhaps a little unclear about the chain rule on manifolds. On a manifold, what is the definition of $$ \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x}$$ and how do we know that we can break up the derivative in this way. I'm sorry, I just seem to especially get stuck on this kind of technical detail with manifolds - perhaps because I have a little trouble chasing the definitions while at the same time incorporating my intuitive understandings.

Comment: Well, $\mu$ is a function $G\times G\to G$, so if you fix $y\in G$, you can consider the function $f:G\to G$ defined by $f(x)=\mu(x,y)$ (of course, this is just what you called $n_y$).  By $\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}$ I just mean by definition the derivative of this map $f$.  So, $\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}$ is a map $T_xG\to T_{xy}G$, and similarly $\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial y}$ is a map $T_yG\to T_{xy}G$.

Comment: The content of the "chain rule" I am using is then just that if we identify $T_{(x,y)}(G\times G)$ with $T_xG\times T_y G$ in the canonical way, then $d\mu:T_{(x,y)}(G\times G)\to T_{xy}G$ is the map $T_xG\times T_y G\to T_{xy} G$ given by $d\mu(v,w)=\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}v+\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial y}w$.  You can prove this by just using the ordinary chain rule for maps $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ in coordinate charts.